# cannot type into tinymce textarea when jquery-ui.min.js is included - MASTERPAGE RELATED

Tags: jquery, tinymce, master-pages

I checked many resources but could not find anyone else having the same issue. Tinymce is not clickable when I include this: `<script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` If I do not have it, it works perfect. If I include it, then I cannot click inside the textarea and type something. The problem is I need to include jquery-ui file.

Do you have any idea what is going on here?

```
<link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../Content/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="../Scripts/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js"></script>

<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea#txt_PostComment",
        theme: "modern",
        menubar: false,
        statusbar: false,
        toolbar_items_size: 'small',
        plugins: [

         "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
         "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
         "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
         "emoticons template paste textcolor"
        ],
        width: '100%',
        toolbar1: "insert file undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright align justify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
        image_advtab: true,
        templates: [
            { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
            { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
        ]
    });


</script>

<textarea id="txt_PostComment">Your content here.</textarea>
```

**UPDATE**

I have this problem only in pages that uses a MasterPage. I tested it in the other pages, it worked great. Do you have any idea why MasterPage causing this?

Below is how it looks when TinyMce is used in a WebForm WITHOUT a Masterpage versus in a Webform WITH a Masterpage. You will see  section becomes empty when in the page with Masterpage, which is the problem.

Not working:

[image: with masterpage]

Working

[image: without masterpage]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a button was clicked, a `Div` containing the TINYMCE textare was displayed with an animation as shown below:

```
$("#pnl_DiscussionWalls").show('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 500);
```

When I replace `sliding-left` animation with `fadeIn`, it just worked perfectly.

```
$("#pnl_DiscussionWalls").fadeIn(500);
```

So, the lesson is that if you have TinyMce in your application, do not use slide animation provided by jquery-ui. It just conflicts with something, and creates trouble. Just go with a simple animation like fadeIn. I hope this helps someone who are having a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use jquery noconflict to resolve this.
 `$.noConflict();`

[fancybox 2 and tinymce jquery conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606872/fancybox-2-and-tinymce-jquery-conflict)

Comment: I updated the question. It still does not work. It works only when Jquery-UI is not included or it is placed before Jquery.js referece. I am using masterpage in asp.net webforms application. Could this be problem?